# Is nltk wordnet lemmatizer language independent?

Tags: nlp, nltk, lemmatization

Is it true that [nltk's wordnet lemmatizer](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/stem/wordnet.html) does not depend on the language of the input text ? Would I use the same sequence of commands:

```
>>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
>>> wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> print(wnl.lemmatize('dogs'))
dog
>>> print(wnl.lemmatize('churches'))
church
>>> print(wnl.lemmatize('aardwolves'))
aardwolf
>>> print(wnl.lemmatize('abaci'))
abacus
>>> print(wnl.lemmatize('hardrock'))
hardrock
```

for both english and french for instance ?

Comment: No, Wordnet lemmatizer in NLTK is only for English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## In Short

No, Wordnet lemmatizer in NLTK is only for English.

## In Long

If we look at https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/stem/wordnet.py#L15

```
class WordNetLemmatizer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def lemmatize(self, word, pos=NOUN):
        lemmas = wordnet._morphy(word, pos)
        return min(lemmas, key=len) if lemmas else word

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<WordNetLemmatizer>'
```

It's based on the `_morphy()` function at https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py#L1764 which applies several [English specific substitutions](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py#L1799)

```
    MORPHOLOGICAL_SUBSTITUTIONS = {
    NOUN: [('s', ''), ('ses', 's'), ('ves', 'f'), ('xes', 'x'),
           ('zes', 'z'), ('ches', 'ch'), ('shes', 'sh'),
           ('men', 'man'), ('ies', 'y')],
    VERB: [('s', ''), ('ies', 'y'), ('es', 'e'), ('es', ''),
           ('ed', 'e'), ('ed', ''), ('ing', 'e'), ('ing', '')],
    ADJ: [('er', ''), ('est', ''), ('er', 'e'), ('est', 'e')],
    ADV: []}

MORPHOLOGICAL_SUBSTITUTIONS[ADJ_SAT] = MORPHOLOGICAL_SUBSTITUTIONS[ADJ]
```